# Select case to find data same in columns

Tags: t-sql

I have this require logic condition and hope someone can help me code this.

If personid > 1 and ipeds column are the same value then report the value else report 'multiple'

```
PersonId    ipeds
408         3
408         3
656         6
656         1
```

I code this but the 'Multiple' condition exist when records in personid repeat even though the ipeds column are not the same.

```
(SELECT
  P.PersonId, CASE WHEN COUNT(P.PersonId) > 1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE MIN(I.Description) END AS IPEDS_Ethnicity
FROM
  PersonEthnicity AS P 
INNER JOIN
  IpedsFederalCategory AS I ON P.IpedsFederalCategoryId = I.IpedsFederalCategoryId
GROUP BY P.PersonId) AS QS ON PEOPLE.PersonId = QS.PersonId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 'Multiple' to be show only when the ipeds are different, you should prepare a query to eliminate the duplication. Just then you can use your logic. Check the example below:

```
create table #t (PersonId int, ipeds int)

INSERT INTO #t VALUES (408, 3), (408, 3), (409, 1), (500, 3), (500, 4)

;WITH dt AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT PersonId, ipeds
    FROM #t
)
SELECT
  P.PersonId, CASE WHEN COUNT(P.PersonId) > 1 
                    THEN 'Multiple' 
                    ELSE CAST(MIN(P.ipeds) as varchar(5)) END AS IPEDS_Ethnicity
FROM
  dt AS P 
GROUP BY P.PersonId
```

Result as follow:
408 3
409 1
500 Multiple

Comment: Fred, thank you for you help. However when i ran your example this is the error i got. "Column 'dt.ipeds' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." And when i put the p.ipeds into the group by the result did not come out as you shown. it show up as PersonId IPEDS_Ethnicity
408 3
409 1
500 3
500 4

Comment: The query is fixed. It was missing the MIN(P.ipeds)